# IOS - Image cut off when dynamically set in UIImageView from camera album

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I am programmatically setting the image in a `UIImageView`, by doing the following

```
    myImageView.image = photo;  // photo is UIImage from the camera album.
```

It would appear that the bottom of the photo image is being cut off.  Since I have the `UIImageView` set to "Aspect fit," I would have figured that the image would be properly scaled to fit the bounds of the `UIImageView`, but that does not appear to be the case.  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong or missing?  The `UIImageView` is set up in a xib file.

Here's the snipped of the xib file where the `UIImageView` is created.

```
  <subviews>
        <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NEf-qh-PaY">
               <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="510"/>
               <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
        </imageView>
  </subviews>
```

The image is the standard dimensions for the iPhone5 camera, namely 2248 x 3264

Comment: can you show image , where you xib or storyboard is making myImageView, and its properties, also dimensions of UIImageView and Image itself. KIndly update code with these, I will try to sort out your problem.

Comment: Veer, thanks for your help! The relevant files can be found in http://megurosystems.com/stackoverflow/